# Retaining the states of Checkbox inside a frgment after returns back from another fragment

Tags: android

They are using a RecyclerView(R1.1) inside a Fragment (F1). Recyclerview R1.1 shows lists of customers, that include a checkbox for each customer in the recyclerview R1.1. They also use 2 Tabs for another type of customer. I have selected the 2nd tab and checked some checkboxes in the recyclerview.

In onCreateView() of Fragment F1, I am calling the web api to get the data to fill the recyclerview R1.1.

Then am calling another fragment (F2) for AdvancedSearch by the code `fragmentTransaction.replace(int,fragment2,fragment2.getTag())`. Then calls another fragment(F3) for showing the search result from F2.

Then back to F2 from F3 and again back to F1. Here I want to get the fragment F1 with the selected 2nd Tab and checkboxes.

I have checked with fragmentTransaction.add(int,fragment,string), but I don't know if this is a good practice.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then you could utilize Room to store the value, which is very easy to work with.

Comment: Yes, this should be done with some database for storing the data for each customer

Comment: Okay, thanks for the valuable comment. will try with the database.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest approach is the one you said. Using the add option, the Fragment keeps the state because it is still alive. If you don't want to maintain the fragment like that, you should use onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState through the parent Activity.